# orientation android

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-orientation

I want to add orientation on my app but I need that--> when my phone on PORTRAIT style works A activity and when I change PORTRAIT style as LANDSCAPE style A activity stops and B activity starts.How can I handle this? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
{   

}
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
{   

}
```

Answer (score 2):

do this

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       //here call activity A
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       //here call activity B

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start your `Activity B` with below code -

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Intent a = new Intent(this, B.class);
        startActivity(a);
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        //do nothing
    }
  }
```

And, in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file's both activity tag. Just declare like below

```
<activity android:name=".A"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Answer (score 0):

First check the orientation this way:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int orientation = display.getOrientation();
```

and start the Activity you wanted depending on the value of orientation.

then in the activity override this method:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

//start the other activity
}
```